# Auth header not being sent with GET requests

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

I currently have express-jwt setup and working with Auth0.  If you specify a authorization token in curl or postman, the page loads correctly.  If you use a browser, the express-jwt middleware says no token was supplied and if I inspect the request headers, there isn't any auth header.

Really boggeling my mind over this, thanks
~ Running express by the way

**edit, added code I've been using for example.  Not sure what else would be necessary.  Its just a simple react app with JWT auth.

```
exports.getTokenData = async function (req) {
try {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        if (!token) return false;

        let res = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://xelitexirish.eu.auth0.com/userinfo',
            headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
        });
        return res.data;
    } else return false;
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`Unable to fetch jwt data, Error: ${err.stack}`);
}
```

};

Thanks

Comment: It will be nice if you share some codes

Comment: Auth0 Dev here, you shouldn't be calling `/userinfo` just to get the userinformation and validate the token, the JWT is validated implcitely using the spec and can be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will only send "standard" headers for any given HTTP request -- by that I mean that, when you add the header in Postman / cURL, you are explicitely telling the HTTP client (Postman / cURL) to send this header with the request. When you are opening the URL on the browser no one is telling the browser it should send your custom header with the request.

You will be able to get this to - temporarily - work by installing [mod_header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) on Chrome and add your custom header for the browser requests but, in real world applications, tokens are generally stored in cookies, or in the localStorage.